# Python GUI for accessibility Application

Tags: python, accessibility

I am to develop a Python-based Application for people with motion problems.

I have read a few posts here about general characteristics of the most used Toolkits for creating GUIs with Python, but hope you can give me some advice according to my requirements.

1) Basically the persons who will use the program, will communicate with it using clicks,
one click meaning "Yes" and when necessary two clicks (not as fast as a double-click) meaning "no".
It doesn't matter the region of the screen where the mouse pointer is, what matters is if it is a click or two clicks.

2) In the main window, the program will display 6 different elements, and must ciclically play a pre-recorde sound for each one,
and wait a short period of time for the user to choose it (by clicking once). By Example:
  Sound "Element one"... Wait n seconds for a click
  Sound "Element two"... wait n seconds for a click
  and so on

If none of the elements is selected, then the program must start again on the first one.

3) Once the user selects one of the options, a new group of elements is presented, and the process of 2) is
repeated, but in this case when a selection is made, the element is added to a "final list".

By Example: the main group of elements being 1) Animals, 2) Countries, 3) Cities,... and
the secondary elements being 1.1) Dog, 1.2) Cat, ...

The final list may be something like: Dog, New York, Mexico, Argentina, Cat, Snake, Egypt, Caracas, ...

4) One of the main elements Group will be "Control Elements", so the user can tell the program when to stop a list, making a pause, etc

5) The program must show the current list as it is being created. In the future, a Speech Synthesizer will be connected to it. A prediction tool will be added too. And the text and images must be large. Very important: The app must work across platforms (Linux and Windows basically). An executable must be generated, at least for windows.

And well, that is. As you can see, it is not a complex problem, but I would really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout [Kivy](http://kivy.org/). You can prototype your application very fast. It's a NUI framework, so some concept are totally adaptable, like double-click: it's named doubletap, and implemented as a input post processor. For example, you can change the timeout between the double tap (or even the distance between 2 tap) for your application by doing:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'double_tap_timeout', '500') #< 500 ms between 2 touch tap
```

And then, detect the action in one of your widget:

```
class MyCustomWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # is the touch is touching on me ?
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return False
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            print 'its a double tap!'
        else:
            print 'its a tap'
        return super(MyCustomWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test kivy in the next days. Is there a way I could generate an executable of my App for Windows?

Comment: what about handling clicks? It must be interpreted the same way (like a "YES") no matter where the pointer is

Comment: exactly the same marco. mouse are handled as a generic input, so click is standard touch in kivy framework.